# Are 64 bit releases for 12.04 or 12.10?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10

Where do I obtain 64 bit 12.04 & 12.10?
My computer is 64 bit.

Answer (score 4):

From http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
On that page, there is a download button for 12.04 and for 12.10, you just need to select 64-bit from the drop down menu.